# How to use ridbag in pyorient?

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I use multi-thread to add edges. But there is an exception which is PyOrientCommandException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConcurrentModificationException - Cannot UPDATE the record #131:1 because the version is not the latest. Probably you are updating an old record or it has been modified by another user (db=v5 your=v4)DB name="tt" 
I know ridbag in Java, but how can I use it in Python?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi @Siqi, have you tried to upgrade the version of Orient and python?